# Anti-swear system not working if message is edited

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Basically if you say something that's not a swear word but then edit the message into a swear word, the bot will not detect it. How do I fix this? Here's my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    for badword in file:
        if badword in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            warnMessage = f"Hey {message.author.mention}! Don't say that!"
            await message.channel.send(warnMessage, delete_after=5.0)
            print(f"{message.author.name} tried saying: {badword}")
            channel = client.get_channel(836232733126426666)
            
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Someone tried to swear!", colour=0x2D2D2D)
            embed.add_field(name="Person who tried to swear:", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="What they tried to say:", value=f"{badword}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Channel they tried to swear in:", value=f"<#{message.channel.id}>", inline=False)
            
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            return
            await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.content.startswith('Jason derulo'):
        await message.channel.send('Wiggle wiggle wiggle')
    if message.content.startswith('fast'):
        await message.channel.send('She a runner she a track star')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `on_message_edit` event for that and use the same logic you're using in the `on_message` event (just remember to use the `after` arg instead of `message`)

```py
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    for badword in file:
        if badword in after.content.lower():
            await after.delete()
            warnMessage = f"Hey {after.author.mention}! Don't say that!"
            await after.channel.send(warnMessage, delete_after=5.0)
            print(f"{message.author.name} tried saying: {badword}")
            channel = client.get_channel(836232733126426666)
            
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Someone tried to swear!", colour=0x2D2D2D)
            embed.add_field(name="Person who tried to swear:", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="What they tried to say:", value=f"{badword}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Channel they tried to swear in:", value=f"<#{message.channel.id}>", inline=False)
            
            return await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

#### Reference:

- [`on_message_edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_edit)